# How to make bootstrap dropdown not change width with different text or not impact other elements?

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, width

I have a bootstrap dropdown with different options. As different options are selected, its width is changed (due to different text length). This causes the items next to it to move. How do I prevent them from moving?

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
<div class="entry">
    <span>1</span> <!--This is the label that I want to fix -->
     <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Not Selected</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item">Not Selected</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item">short</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item">This is long text</a>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Here is my [jsbin with all the code](https://jsbin.com/lovidimiqo/edit?html,output).

The number labels (1-5) move around whenever the size of the button changes, making everything look disorganized and unappealing. How do I either prevent it from moving or have a fixed width for the dropdown that is guaranteed to fit all the text?

Comment: Need to edit the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a width to your button class, as follows, this will stop it from changing depending on the value that is selected.

```
.btn-success {
    width:250px;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0yur1s42/

Comment: Can also add a max-width, just in case:
.btn-success{
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

Comment: It worked when I specified 250px as min-width and 100% as max-width. Please update your answer with max-width. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the CSS for `ul.dropdown-menu`

The measurements to set fixed width are:

```
max-width
min-width
```

---

Fix width for

```
<span>1</span> <!--This is the label that I want to fix -->
```

Change to

```
<span style='width=100px'>1</span> <!--This is the label that I want to fix -->
```

Change 100px to whatever width you need

---

For Button:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
```

Change CSS in stylesheet or change that line to:

```
 <div class="btn-group" style='width=100px'>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

friend I modify the css of .btn class this is the codepen like this

```css
.btn{
   min-width: 131px;
    max-width: 131px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      .number{
        font-size: 3vw;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 3px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container text-center">
      
      <!-- template for one dropdown -->
      <template id="template">
        <div class="entry">
          <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Not Selected</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item">Not Selected</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item">short</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item">This is very long text</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      //generates 5 dropdowns concisely (instead of copying and pasting HTML code)
      var template = document.getElementById("template")
      for(var i = 1; i<=5; i++){
        //creates span with number
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        var num = document.createTextNode(i);
        span.setAttribute("class", "number");
        span.appendChild(num);
        
        //adds span to the template
        var clon = template.content.cloneNode(true);
        clon.childNodes[1].prepend(span); 
        document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].appendChild(clon);
      }
 
      $(document).ready(function(){
        //replaces text in the dropdown with current selection
        $(".dropdown-item").on("click", function(){
          $(this).parent().prev().text($(this).text());
        });
              });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/Qleoz12/pen/NempvQ?editors=1100

take in mind that the longtext in some cases may overflow

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following CSS property to fix that problem:

```
.btn-group button{
    width:130px !important;
}
```